# Deploying Akka HTTP to Azure

Tags: java, azure, sbt, akka-http

I was looking for some info on how to deploy Akka Http app to Azure. Azure supports Java Web Apps, but I assume it does only for apps that run in TomCat or alike. But Akka Http is a standalone application - is there any support for that and in any case, how should I proceed with it?

I am aware of sbt-native-packager that can produce various installable formats, but seeing how easy it is to deploy .NET app from Visual Studio, I would love to see a simpler way for Java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, your app using Akka Http is a standalone jar file which need to be deployed on Azure WebApps. Please refer to the section [`Application configuration Examples`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload#application-configuration-examples) of the offical tutorial `Upload a custom Java web app to Azure` to create a `web.xml` file in the path `wwwroot` to deploy your app like these samples `Jetty` or `Springboot`.

Comment: I don't thinks Jetty or Springboot is an answer here. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940867/5018962

Comment: @eddyP23 Following the sample of `Jetty` or `Springboot` to configure a jar file as a runnable server on Azure WebApps. You need to change the bind port of akka http with the code `sys.env("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT")` which is dispatched automatically by Azure, not customized.